# Spring Boot session scoped bean not reused in RestController across requests

Tags: java, spring-boot, session, scope, javabeans

In my application I have to do an expensive initialization of a bean that is dependent on the logged in user. I would like to create the bean once a new session is created and reuse it across all requests within the session.

The problem is that the bean is recreated on every request (which is exactly what I wanted to avoid). It seems that Spring is not able to determine the session and creates a new one on every request.

I am using Spring Security to do the authentication and authorization of the requests. My assumption was that Spring is able to determine a formally created session by the credentials used for the request but maybe this is wrong.

Here are the relevant code snippets:

**The session-scoped bean within a @Configuration class**

```
@Bean
@SessionScope
public SessionScopedBean sessionScopedBean() {
    String username = SecurityContextHolder
            .getContext()
            .getAuthentication()
            .getName();
    return doTheExpensiveInitializationOfSessionScopedBean(username);
}
```

I want this bean to be reused per session. However Spring is calling this method on every request.

**Usage of SessionScopedBean in @RestController**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/items")
@Transactional
public class ItemService {

    @Resource(name = "sessionScopedBean")
    SessionScopedBean sessionScopedBean;

    @GetMapping
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
    public Items getAllItems() {
        return sessionScopedBean.getAllItems()
    }
}
```

**WebSecurityConfiguration**

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(new CORSFilter(), JWTAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtSecret))
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtSecret))
            // this disables session creation on Spring Security
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER);
}
```

Why is the sessionScopedBean recreated on every request to /items even though the same authentication token is reused? How does Spring determine sessions in RestControllers anyways?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: // this disables session creation on Spring Security
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER);

^^ could that be the reason? 

Spring has to have some way of deciding that requests are part of the same session.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/request/SessionScope.java


 @Override
 public String getConversationId() {
  return RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSessionId();
 }

Looks like it uses a sessionID (probably not your jwt)

Comment: I tried it without this line and with other parameters -> same result
As far as I understand the documentation there are two different sessions: sessions generated by Spring Security and the web sessions generated by MVC.